# JSON Stringify - PHP json_decode

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am new to JSON,ofr a project of my own I need to send array of objects to the server. Basically, I have a Question object, which has a couple of properties, like question, optionA, optionB etc. I have an array of Question objects.

example:

```
qArray = new Array();
qArray.push(new Question("where do you live?", "England", "ıtaly", "Usa");
```

I am adding a lot of questions objects to this array and in the end, I need to send this array to the server, like this:

```
$.post("backend-stuff/aj-save-test.php", { testName : $("#testName").val().toString(), 'questions' : JSON.stringify(qArray)}, function(result){
        alert(result);
    });
}
```

In PHP, I use this,

```
$questions = json_decode($_POST["questions"]);
$testName = $_POST["testName"];
```

Problem is that I cant read data, either I am sending it in the wrong way or whats wrong is on the php side.

Thank you for answers, I checked Google before sending the question, so please forgive me if this is so easy but for me its not so.

Comment: What's the error message? What's `var_dump($questions);`?

Comment: I'm not sure, but If I remember well you don't need to use json_decode here, since you're already passing an array structure, so you can manipulate $questions as php array structure

Comment: No. PHP does _not_ detect it as JSON and decode it for you.

Comment: I am trying to print the result, I mean I am echoing out $questions to check, and alerting that via Javascript ajax. But it either says 'Array'. - UPDATE: While I was checking this again, I see that echo cant print arrays so  I used print_r() function and now it prints like this: Array( [0] => stdClassObject ( [question] => bla bla, [optionA] => a, [optionB] => b,) ...) and continues. But there is still one thing I dont know, what is stdClassObject and now it is possible for me to fetch this array and save questions to database right? I think there no extra work except this.

Answer (score 1):

To convert stdClassObject to an array, check out [get_object_vars()](https://www.php.net/get_object_vars).

Comment: This is exactly what I did, my Object constructor prototype is exactly like this. I was only getting 'Array' when I try to alert, and i guess its because i used echo not print_r. But thank you, for trying to helping me.

Comment: No problem. You're correct in that you would then want to take this data from your array, sanitize and validate it, and then enter it into your database.